# how to display span tag values separated by a break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span tag,`<span id="display"></span>`
and getting the span text by `$("#display").html();`

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   var val = $("#display").html();
   if (val == "") {
      $("#display").html(arr[i].name);
      $("display").html('<img src ="/Home/Image?id = arr[i].id"/>')
     }
   else {
      $("#display").html(val +" <br/> " + arr[i].name);
     $("display").html('<img src ="/Home/Image?id = arr[i].id"/>')
   }
}
```

I want to display like name and Image of each record with a break.I have imlemented like above,name is displaying but image is not displaying.
I want to display like,name and image tag

Comment: you want `html()`, not `text()`

Comment: what is the o/p are you expecting?

Comment: display all names with a downword arrow.

Comment: What do you mean by downward arrow?

Comment: can you give some sample output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#display").html(val +" <br/> " + arr[i].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var val = $("#display").html();

    if (val == "") {
        $("#display").html(arr[i].name);
    }
    else {
        $("#display").html(val +" <br/> " + arr[i].name);
    }
}
```

OR

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var val = $("#display").text();

    if (val == "") {
        $("#display").text(arr[i].name);
    }
    else {
        $("#display").text(val +" \n " + arr[i].name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of text():

```
 if (val == ""){
     $("#display").html(arr[i].name);
 }
 else {
     $("#display").html(val +" <br/> " + arr[i].name);
 }
```